# Terminal cursor movement stutters when mouse cursor is hovered over terminal

Tags: cursor, emacs-nox

I using emacs-nox with Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

The problem I'm facing is that whenever my mouse cursor is hovering over the terminal window, I experience very *stuttery* cursor movement.


As you can see in the first gif the mouse cursor is rapidly blinking on and off.

Perhaps it is because I have my cursor movement keys bound to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

**Up =** <kbd>Alt-i</kbd> **Down =** <kbd>Alt-k</kbd> **Left =** <kbd>Alt-j</kbd> **Right =** <kbd>Alt-l</kbd>


Does anyone know how to go about fixing this annoyance, or perhaps a work-around?


[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you see this when starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)?

Comment: Yes, same exact behavior.

Comment: Offhand that sounds like a terminal problem rather than an Emacs problem.  Have you attempted to reproduce this issue (or similar) when running things other than Emacs?  Have you tested this in a different terminal emulator? (Ideally not one based on the same code as the one you're currently using.)

Comment: If you haven't already done so, you can surely confirm or reject your `Alt` key hypothesis very easily, and update the question accordingly.